# How to filter null values in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: filter, null, pyspark

Suppose we have a simple dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
StructField('id', LongType(), False),
StructField('name', StringType(), False),
StructField('count', LongType(), True),
])
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'Alice',None), (2,'Bob',1)], schema)
```

The question is how to detect null values? I tried the following:

```
df.where(df.count == None).show()
df.where(df.count is 'null').show()
df.where(df.count == 'null').show()
```

It results in error:

```
condition should be string or Column
```

I know the following works:

```
df.where("count is null").show()
```

But is there a way to achieve with without the full string? I.e. `df.count`...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Spark Function [`isnull`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.isnull)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.where(F.isnull(F.col("count"))).show()
```

or directly with the method [`isNull`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isNull)

```
df.where(F.col("count").isNull()).show()
```

Comment: And for those unfamiliar with pyspark syntax likeme, `.isNotNull()` gives you everywhere that is not null.

Comment: `~F.col("count").isNull()` also works to provide the negation

Answer (score 9):

Another way of doing the same is by using `filter` api

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.filter(F.isnull("count")).show()
```

Comment: Is there any significant difference between `where` and `filter`? I mean generally, not only in this case.

Comment: @MiroslavStola,**`where` is an alias for `filter`**. `filter` is standard for functional programming whereas `where` is for those who prefer SQL ways.